# Highlight Select Box in Python

Tags: python, pygtk, selection, xlib

I am trying to rebuild the functionality of the desktop's "highlight to select" feature so that I can use it in my own app.  When I say "highlight to select" I mean the selection box that shows up if you click and drag on your desktop (native to all main-stream OS).

I've been working for hours trying to recreate it, and simply can't find a way.  I've tried PyGTK, Xlib for python, and a couple other weird hacks.  All of which have their own problems that won't allow me to move forward.

I generally don't ask for straight up example code without providing some sort of starting point, but in this project I don't even know where to start.  How would you do this?

Here's the requirements:

- Must draw on the root window (or a transparent layer that "appears" to be the root)
- Must return the coordinates of the selection (x, y, height width)

**Update:**  Forgot some details.

- I am using Ubuntu 10.10
- I have dual monitors (though, I don't think that should matter)
- I don't mind downloading any extra libraries that are necessary

Comment: Can you handle onclick/release handlers with pygtk?  Can you draw a box on the screen?  If so, what more do you need?

Comment: The hardest part of the problem is drawing a box on the root window - not on child window/widget.  I have not successfully drawn anything on the root window using pygtk.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you're looking for, but what if you created another window in your module, and have your code show it when you release drag? You could fetch the cursor's current position, and have it draw the window there.

[This should help you get the mouse position on the root window.](http://faq.pygtk.org/index.py?req=show&file=faq23.024.htp)

So, your code may look a little like this (this is untested code!) I'm only showing the relevant portions of what goes inside __ init __.

```
def __init__(self):

    ...
    #Some of your code here.
    ...

    win = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)

    #Note that I am creating a popup window separately.
    popwin = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_POPUP)

    #I am setting "decorated" to False, so it will have no titlebar or window controls.
    #Be sure to compensate for this by having another means of closing it.
    popwin.set_decorated(False)

    def ShowPopup():
        #You may need to put additional arguments in above if this is to be an event. 
        #For sake of example, I'm leaving this open ended.

        #Get the cursor position.            
        rootwin = widget.get_screen().get_root_window()
        curx, cury, mods = rootwin.get_pointer()

        #Set the popup window position.
        popwin.move(curx, cury)
        popwin.show()

    def HidePopup():
        #This is just an example for how to hide the popup when you're done with it.
        popwin.hide()

    ...
    #More of your code here.
    ...

    #Of course, here is the code showing your program's main window automatically.
    win.show()
```

A very simplistic approach, but it should give the appearance of what you're wanting.